# A question about binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Regarding binomial distribution, is one person making n repeated  decisions the same as n-person making one time decision simultaneously?

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Provided each decision is a binary choice, yes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flipping one (fair) coin ten times is the same as flipping ten (fair) coins all at once.

That's a useful thing to remember when you want to convince someone that after a row of heads tails don't become more likely in order to catch up.

For a person making decisions it might be hard to claim that they are independent when they are sequential.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation , I was just getting into probability, your answer helps wrap my head around it. Yes, because those are independent choices. Thank you.